# C dynamic pointer array allocation. Why can I access elements out of range?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int *jagged[1];
jagged[0] = calloc(2, 4);
jagged[0][100] = 2;
printf("%d\n", jagged[0][100]);
```

I have allocated 2 elements jagged[0] why can I access jagged[0][100] ?

Comment: because undefined behaviour includes appear to work.

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't hinder you to call undefined behavior.

Comment: You should hardly ever use `{c,m,re}alloc` or built-in arrays or pointers in C++. There is nothing gcc-specific in this code.

Comment: I need to use jagged int arrays in C with dynamic memory allocation. How do I do it?

Comment: @hellomyfriends Then don't tag the question c++. They are very different languages

Answer (score 2):

Because you can not! :-) The compiler did not check any logical or range errors. Maybe your OS or hardware will terminate the process if the memory access violates any memory boundary. To check such thinks use valgrind or other memory analyzing tools. On embedded systems you can check with a lot of simulating environments.

If your process runs it overwrites other maybe senseful data and your program runs into trouble which is typically hard to find. So please use external tools to fix such problems early as possible. We run valgrind and static code analysis tools after each commit automatically!

Also have a look for address sanatizer delivered with a lot of modern compilers like clang and g++. Thread & address sanitizing is really a must in "best practice" programming.

https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer