# printing values of dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays

I have made a dynamic array of integers in C, here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int count=0, i, input;
   int *myarr;
   myarr=(int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

   while(1){
     scanf("%d", &input);
     myarr[count]=input;
     count++;
     if (input == -1) break;
   }

   for (i=0; i<count; i++){
     printf("%d ", myarr[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

From the code, I thought i clearly made an array of 4 integers only i.e myarr[0] up to myarr[3], how come when i insert even 10 integers, it still prints all of them, it doesn't print garbage as i thought it would after the fourth integer... Maybe i didn't understand the point of dynamic creating an array?? Make me straight please!

Comment: myarr[0] to myarr[3] not myarr[4]

Comment: @Venkatesh sorry i didn't see that, thanks i fixed it already

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648635/c-dynamic-pointer-array-allocation-why-can-i-access-elements-out-of-range

Comment: There are many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Answer (score 0):

You should only access `myarr[0]` up to and including `myarr[3]`.

Accessing any other index is *undefined behaviour*: it might work, it might not.

Also, `myarr[count]==input` looks like a typo. Did you mean `myarr[count] = input`? The way you have it is testing if `myarr[count]` *equals* `input`. Technically the way you have it is *undefined behaviour* for *any* element of `myarr` since you are making use of uninitialised data.

Comment: So it depends on the compiler??

Comment: It could depend on the compiler, the weather, or what you ate last night.

Comment: About the assignment operator, i fixed it already.. typing mistake